# How to play a song continuously if a condition is met?

Tags: python

I want to play a sound continuously in python with playsound module however there's always a delay before the song restart. How to remove that delay?

I want the sound to be played with no delay at all only when a certain condition is met.

Code:

```
from tkinter import * 
import threading
import time
from playsound import playsound  

entry1 = StringVar()
entry1 = Entry(root)
entry1.place(x=0, y=0, width=70, height=30)

def getSound():
    while True: 
        time.sleep(0.00001) 
        if (entry1.get() == "PLAY"): 
         playsound('sound.mp3')
        
thread = threading.Thread(target= lambda :  getSound(), daemon=True)
thread.start()
```

Comment: can you include the library ? not sure if its winsound

Comment: if it was .Wav theres a much more robust library called winsound

Comment: You think windsound will work for this purpose ? The problem is that it doesn't want to play the sound without interruption with playsound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out(If typed text is PLAY it loops else it stops):

```
from tkinter import *
from winsound import PlaySound, SND_FILENAME, SND_LOOP, SND_ASYNC
import winsound

def callback(sv):    
    if(sv.get()=="PLAY"):
     winsound.PlaySound("Sound.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME|SND_LOOP|SND_ASYNC)
    else:
     winsound.PlaySound(None, SND_FILENAME)


root = Tk()
entry1 = StringVar()
entry1.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, sv=entry1: callback(sv))
e = Entry(root, textvariable=entry1)
e.pack()
root.mainloop()
```